# Modify the native wordpress gallery to use FlexSlider 2

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Regards,

I need to be able to change the native wordpress gallery to be able to implement the **FlexSlider 2** plugin, [specifically this module or feature](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html) but I can not find the way to do it.

You can help me with this that has me crazy ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a ready plugin for this. https://wordpress.org/plugins/flexslider-for-native-gallery/

To match your requirement. I modified its code a little bit and uploaded on github.

https://github.com/projoomexperts/Flexslider-Carousel-For-Wordpress-Native-Gallery

Comment: Pleace review https://github.com/projoomexperts/Flexslider-Carousel-For-Wordpress-Native-Gallery/issues/1